# DELPHI 7 Read ASCII Text file into BDE TTable

Tags: delphi

I have this headache when i'm trying to read Ascii Text file line by line (with Fixed length) and parse it into a BDE TTable. I have created two file for testing purpose, but always end up having an error "Data Structure Corruption".

```
TESTING.TXT : ---> The Text File
201305IMPA200DTA090005000RONALDPA
201406IMPA200DTA090001000JESS  LN
201209IMPA200DTA090002500MICAH PA 

TESTING.SCH : ---> The Schema File
[TESTING]
FILETYPE=FIXED
CHARSET=ASCII
Field1=DATA_TYPE,CHAR,13,00,00
Field2=ID_DATA,CHAR,06,00,13
Field3=AMOUNT,CHAR,06,00,19
Field4=NAME,CHAR,06,00,25
Field5=CODE,CHAR,02,00,31
```

Explanation : The Field3 is zero padded, The Field4 is space included (if 6 char length not meet).

as you can see in the SCH it's fixed length, and i have thousand of rows to work with.

Comment: where is source code?

Comment: By using BDE Ttable I don't have to use any code, since all the options can be changed in the properties of Ttable, such as: 
DatabaseName : C:\           --> (TXT Location)
TableName : TESTING.TXT      --> (Name of Table/TXT File)
TableType : ttASCII          --> (Table type using ASCII for TXT File)
I just have to set True in Active Properties of Ttable then all the field will goes into TDBGRid

Comment: Are any of your field names reserved words? For example `NAME` or `CODE`. Try appending an `x` to each to see if that helps.

Comment: okay now i got it work, the ttable loads the text file into fields according the settings in sch file, but the ttable only read the second line (row) until the last line (row) of my text file. The first line in my text file is skipped, perhaps the first line is considered as a header or something, did i miss anything?

Comment: "perhaps the first line is considered as a header or something" - probably.  "did i miss anything?" Apart from the BDE having been obsolete for more than a decade, you mean?  Seriously, consider using something else, like ADO, before you get too far involved in this.

Comment: @Martyn: The question mentions Delphi 7; somehow I don't think obsolescence is a concern. :-)

Comment: @Ken White: Indeed ;-) Otoh, I still find D7 a better tool than its successors for a quick testbed to investigate SO qs that don't involve their added language features.  Much faster, less fiddly and doesn't take over the screen, etc, ... ime

Comment: @KenWhite : i'm aware of that, but my source data here is actually a fixed length text imported to a bde table with the size between 6 to 10 Mb Max. i just need the ascii fixed length text to be read and then to be imported back to ascii text format.

Comment: The BDE32.hlp file contains nothing that allows you to indicate whether the first row is a header or not (search for "schema" in the index, and then double-click the "file" item beneath it). As the only issue you have now (based on what you wrote in the comment above) is that the first row is being skipped, and there seems to be no way documented for not doing so, I don't have a solution. I haven't used the BDE since Delphi 1, and I find it much easier to just write a quick console app to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @KenWhite : thanks a lot the help file really does help a lot.